# SQL UPDATE, WHERE conditions limitation (index stop work)

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, where-clause

Index stop working if i have some multiple OR pairs like ((ID = 5 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-17 05:56:19.0'))

SQL Where clauses has limitations? SQL optimizer decide to use full scan?
Database query settings restrictions?

I can split sql to small peaces.

```
EXPLAIN
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE
      SET MY_FLAG=1
      WHERE (ID = 1 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-15 01:24:01.0') ||
            (ID = 2 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-15 02:14:02.0') ||
            (ID = 3 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-16 03:32:08.0') ||
            (ID = 4 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-16 04:45:19.0') ||
            (ID = 5 AND TEST_DATE = '2019-01-17 05:56:19.0')
```

Explain results1: OR pairs > 200

```
(1, 'SIMPLE', 'TEST_TABLE', 'range', 'PRIMARY,test_date_index', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, 316, 'Using where');
```

Explain results2: OR pairs > 300

```
(1, 'SIMPLE', 'TEST_TABLE', 'index', NULL, 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, 51425278, 'Using where');
```

Table strucute:

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST_TABLE` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ATTR_ADDRESS` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ATTR_CITY` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ATTR_COUNTRY` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TEST_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `MY_FLAG` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `test_date_index` (`TEST_DATE`),
    INDEX `MY_FLAG` (`MY_FLAG`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: You have an index on (id,test_date) ?

Comment: Yes primary id and secondary test_date_index.

Comment: Is the table InnoDB?

Comment: Yes, InnoDB. Current database is MariaDB 10.0.x.

Comment: In which case, I cannot see any further scope for optimisation here - but hopefully others will be able to suggest something.

Comment: Solution is USE FORCE INDEX(test_date_index) or small updates.

Comment: "an index on (id,test_date)" is _not_ the same as "primary id and secondary test_date_index".  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table` so we can see which it is.

Comment: Are there 51M rows in the table?

Comment: Yes, more 51m rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optimizer does not have sufficient information to decide which way is better for performing the query.  If you have found that, say, 200 is a safe limit for "faster" execution, then chunk it.  That is, do only 200 rows at a time.

Alternatively, you could try putting the ID, date pairs in another table, then do a "Multi-table `UPDATE`".  It *may* run faster.  Include the "composite" `INDEX(test_date, id)` in `test_table`.